# List values are not binding to mobile ListView in kendoui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Web Service for retrieving values from the database.I have Written Fallowing code for binding List values from web service to mobile List View.but values are not displaying in List View.Is there any problem for binding data from the DB.

```
<div data-role="view" id="flat" data-init="mobileListViewDataBindInitFlat" data-title="ListView"
    data-layout="databinding">
    <ul id="flat-listview">
    </ul>
</div>    

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function () {
        var dataS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'mobileAppWebService.asmx/EmployeeNames',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                },
                schema: {
                    data: 'd'
                }
            }
        });

        $("#flat-listview").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource: dataS,
            template: "${ename}"
        });

    });       
</script>
<script>
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div data-role="view" id="grouped" data-init="mobileListViewDataBindInitGrouped"
    data-transition="" data-title="ListView" data-layout="databinding">
    <ul id="grouped-listview">
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="ListViewTemplate">
    <div class="GetEmployeeData">
        <p>${EName}</p>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function mobileListViewDataBindInitFlat() {
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "MobileAppService.asmx/GetEmployeeData",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#flat-listview").kendoMobileListView({
                    dataSource: data.d,
                    template: $("#ListViewTemplate").html()
                });
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
  var app = new kendo.mobile.Application();

</script>
```

try like this